# Using a function as statement in while loop JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, callback, do-while

I believe similar questions have been posted before, but I don't entirely understand why using a callback function as a While loop statement, such as seen below, results in an infinite loop:

```
do {
    console.log("repeat");
} while(myFunc);

function myFunc(){
    return false;
}
```

This version, on the other hand, prints "repeat" once and then stops:

```
do {
    console.log("repeat");
} while(myFunc === false);
```

Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried invoking the function?

do {
    console.log("repeat");
} while(myFunc());

Comment: Functions are variables in JS. Your function is not being called because you don't have the trailing `()`. That means you are comparison the function variable itself, not the result of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myFunc` is a variable (all functions in JS are object variables), and it's not equal to `false`.

`myFunc()` on the other hand, is the results of `myFunct` being called, and **is** equal to `false`.

So you should compare the result of the function, not the function itself, by calling it:

```
do {
    console.log("repeat");
} while(myFunc() === false);
```

Comment: You shouldn't compare the result of the function against `false` though. You should just write `… while(! myFunc());`

Comment: IDK why you'd like to inverse the condition though,
It's a lot more natural to test for positive cases, so while(myFunc()) and adjust the logic in `myFunc`

Answer (score -1):

Abosolutely agree with the comment, the condition you are checking is always truthy, be myFunc is a pointer to and Object Function.

You must invoke to get out of infinite loop